# Склонение фамилии Середа?

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Склоняется ли женская фамилия Середа?

Answer (score 1):

По нормам фамилии на -а славянского происхождения склоняются как в мужском, так и женском варианте. Происхождение же фамилии *Середа* явно не из Франции.

> Среди фамилий с ударным á после согласных есть как морфологически
>   членимые, так и нечленимые, т. е. несклоняемые.
>
> Несклоняемы фамилии французского происхождения: Дюма, Тома, Дега,
>   Люка, Ферма, Гамарра, Петипа и др.
>
> Фамилии иного происхождения (славянские, из восточных языков)
>   склоняются по первому склонению, т. е. в них вычленяется ударное
>   окончание -а: Митта — Митты, Митте, Митту, Миттой; сюда относятся:
>   Сковорода, Кочерга, Кваша, Цадаса, Хамза и др.

**Н. А. Еськова. Трудности словоизменения существительных**